# Selenium wont click an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

What I am trying to do is click a button to open a drop down menu and click what I want to select using selenium

```
driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/groups/650266/Trade#!/about")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-group-btn').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("role-36901726").click()
```

Error message I receive is

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element
has zero size
```

```
--This is also the Image of the Button I want to click It drops down a menu
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmWE4.png
```

Comment: I see 2 matching elements in the page for the given class name., _always_ make sure to use locator that identifies only one element. Change the class name to `group-dropdown` instead of `input-group-btn`

Comment: Worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question but you can pick values/text/index by using Select class in selenium that is solution for dropdown buttons